# Spring for Android, file upload/download progess

Tags: android, spring, android-progressbar

I start using Spring framework in my Android project to upload/download file from server. 
My problem is how to update progress when uploading/downloading? Anyone have ideas?

My code for upload file using Spring:

```
public String editPersonalAvatar(UserProfile user, String url) {
        String result = "";
        File file = new File(user.getAvatar());
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> mapWithFile;
        mapWithFile = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        mapWithFile.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateHelper().createRestTemplate(new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
                                                                   new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, mapWithFile, String.class);

        return result;
    }
```

Other problem: I request a HTTPPOST to server, and receive a large JSON (example 2MB). Can I calculate the percentage downloading?

Example code:

```
public static String confirmGetFile(String url, String username,String id) throws Exception {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
                map.add("user", username);

        map.add("id", id);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateHelper().createRestTemplate(new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
                                                                                new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, map, String.class);
        Log.d("***RESULT CONFIRM", result);
        return result;
    }
```